# Function parameter is not being defined

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to give the parameter a value so that I can use it in other functions, but when I try to see if it works, it tells me that it's not defined. (The value is randomly picked from a list, as you guys can see below) How can I fix this?

```
import random

player_choice = raw_input("which hand do you wanna play?: ")

def hand_process(computer_choice):
    hand_list = ["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
    chosen_hand = random.randrange(0,len(hand_list))
    computer_choice = hand_list[chosen_hand]
    print computer_choice
    return computer_choice

def main():
    if player_choice == hand_process(computer_choice):
        print "It's a tie"
    else:
        print "Well then..."
```

main()

Comment: what parameter? what value? what's not defined? show us your full traceback and your input

Comment: You never define the `computer_choice` variable in the `main` function. I also don't know why you take an argument of `computer_choice` in the `hand_process` function when you change the variable in the function.

Comment: The parameters of the function are not where you get data *out* of a function; they're where you pass data *into* the function. You don't need a `computer_choice` argument to use the function's return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few errors:

1. hand_list spelled differently in different lines
2. computer_choice does not have to be passed in since it is evaluated in main()

Here is code that works, the way you want

```
import random

player_choice = raw_input("which hand do you wanna play?: ")

def hand_process():
    hand_list = ["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
    chosen_hand = random.randrange(0,len(hand_list))
    computer_choice = hand_list[chosen_hand]
    print computer_choice
    return computer_choice

def main():
    if player_choice == hand_process():
        print "It's a tie"
    else:
        print "Well then..."

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

first: don't exist computer_choice when you call hand_process in main function

second: python is case sensitive, so Hand_list != hand_list in hand_process function

last: look for `random.choice`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function `main`, you have not defined a variable called `computer_choice`. This is why Python complains that it doesn't find it.

Note that `Hand_list` is different from `hand_list`.

And there's a [much easier way to pick a random element from your list.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)